# Apple Mach-O Linker Error: 17 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Tags: xcode

I have the following "Apple Mach-O Linker" error:

```
ld: 17 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What could the cause be? I think this happened after I copied the app b

Comment: "What could the cause be?" - It **just told you what it is:** "17 duplicate symbols".

Comment: As H2CO3 pointed out, you are linking an object file with the same symbols more than once into the final binary.  Without more information that is as much help as anyone can give.